# Functions satisfying $f^{-1}(\frac{1}{f})=f'$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am looking for a function $f$ that satisfies the following condition $f^{-1}(\frac{1}{f})=f'$.

$f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $f$,

**Note1:** The notation $f'$ means derivative of the real valued function $f$

**Note2:**   Sorry, I edited the question because I got it wrong \

I didn't mean to offend anyone, I respect you all
When I said that the answer $f(x)=1$ is not a solution, I mean it is a special solution

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: A simple example is $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: What you mean with $\acute{f}$ (`\acute{f}`)? The derivative of $f$?

Comment: Yes, what else? @emacsdrivesmenuts

Comment: @WillSherwood I have never seen that notation used for the derivative, although I've seen $f'(x)$ and $\dot{f}(x)$.  I definitely don't feel comfortable just taking for granted that this is the intention.

Comment: @Aaron, the user is  from Algeria  , and in Algeria we use this notation f' means derivative of f

Comment: $\acute{f} $ dérivative

Comment: @matrice01abdou Fair enough, but the accent mark was being placed directly above the f, not in the top right corner, and placement can make a big difference in meaning.  That difference in placement was why I was unsure.   More to the point, the thing you are saying means the derivative is NOT what was written.  $f'(x)\neq \acute{f}(x)$. They can both be different notations for the same thing, but they are not the same notation.

Answer (score 3):

$$f^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{f(x)}\bigg) = f(x)$$

Apply $f$ both sides to get

$$\frac{1}{f(x)} = f(f(x))$$

Let $y = f(x)$ to get

$$f(y) = \frac{1}{y}$$

Ad in fact the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ satisfies the functional equation

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question because I got it wrong

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 1$ is one such function. You said you were just looking for one, after all.. One may check,

$$f^{-1}(1/f)=f'$$
$$f(f^{-1}(1/f))=f(f')$$
$$1/f=f(f')$$
and indeed, when it is satisfied for $f(x)=1$.

Comment: But $f(x) = 1$ isn't even invertible

Comment: It is as long as the domain is $[1]$ :)

Comment: Then I suppose $f'$ is not defined will be your complaint then? Fair enough

Comment: somehow the form I came to in this question $f(f')f = 1$ feels like it should elucidate something anyway. Let me know if you figure it out

Comment: @WillSherwood If you restrict the domain to only $\{1\}$ you still have problems.
$$1/f(1)=f(f'(1)) \\ 1=f(0)=\text{undefined}$$
Not to mention that unless your domain is a connected set, the derivative isn't even defined.